# State's value of a class component keep going back to default value even after an update

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Below is the code for a class component which render a button based on a condition, **componentdidmount** is triggering a request to backend to check whether a container is deployed with that id or not. If it is not deployed it will render a deployed button or if it is deployed it will render a kill button.
Now the issue is that the deployed state which is initialized as 1 i.e. not deployed keeps going back to default. Even if the container is deployed it will send true in the response when the **componentdidmount** is called by parent but after a few milli sec it go back to default value. I don't want that I want my component to retain the new value.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Button } from 'antd';
        
    export class Deploy extends Component {
        
            state = {
                deployed: 1,  // 0 means true ie deployed, 1 means false ie not deployed, 2 means error
                url: ""
            };
        
            componentDidMount() {
                const url = "http://ip:3001/check?run_id="+this.props.modelVersion.run_id;
                fetch(url)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log("data"+ data);
                        if(data[0]) {
                            // deployed
                            this.setState({
                                deployed: 0,
                                url: data[1]
                            });
                        }
                        this.setState({
                            // not deployed
                            deployed: 1,
                            url: data[1]
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        // service is down
                        this.setState({
                            deployed: 2
                        });
                    });
            }
            
            onClickDeploy = () => {
                const url = "http://ip:3001/deploy?run_id="+this.props.modelVersion.run_id;
                fetch(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw Error("Some issue with Fastapi server. Check logs for more information.");
                    }
                    return response.json()})
                .then((data) => {
                    // console.log(data)
                    alert(data)
                    this.setState({
                        deployed: 0,
                        url: data
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    // service is down
                    alert(err.message);
                    this.setState({
                        deployed: 2
                    });
                });
            }
        
            onClickKill = () => {
                const url = "http://ip:3001/delete?run_id="+this.props.modelVersion.run_id;
                fetch(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw Error("Some issue with Fastapi server. Check logs for more information.");
                    }
                    return response.json()})
                .then((data) => {
                    // console.log(data.detail)
                    alert(data)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    // service is down
                    alert(err.message);
                    this.setState({
                        deployed: 2
                    });
                });
                this.setState({
                    deployed: 1
                })
            }
        
            deployButton() {
                return(
                    <Button
                        type='primary'
                        onClick={this.onClickDeploy}>
                        Deploy
                    </Button>
                )
            }
        
            killButton(props) {
                // console.log(props);
                return(
                    <>
                        <Button
                            type='primary'
                            onClick={this.onClickKill}>
                            Kill
                        </Button>
                        <p>url: {props}</p>
                    </>
                )
            }
        
            disableButton() {
                return(
                    <Button
                        type='primary'
                        disabled={true}>
                        BackEnd is Down
                    </Button>
                )
            }
            
        
            render() {  
                const {deployed, url} = this.state;
                console.log(deployed);
                console.log(url);
                if(deployed==0) {
                    // console.log("killbutton");
                    return this.killButton(url);
                }
                if(deployed==1) {
                    // console.log("Deploybutton");
                    return this.deployButton();
                }
                return this.disableButton();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were setting the state `if data[0]` in `if` but again you were setting the state directly so even it used to be executed line wise. Adding `else` will keep in chec that if `data[0]` then only it will set or else it will set `deployed:1`

```
if (data[0]) {
    // deployed
    this.setState({
        deployed: 0,
        url: data[1],
    });
} else { // you just missed this else block
    this.setState({
        // not deployed
        deployed: 1,
        url: data[1],
    });
}
```

If there's 1 truthy value for `data[0]` then using such `if` condition is okay but if you have like if `data[0]` with more than 1 truthy value then it's better to compare it in `if` and `else if`

Comment: Thanks it worked... Bt i have a doubt... As per my knowledge a component get rerendered when it's state gets changed... So why we need else block it should rerendered after if block

Comment: Yes but issue was that it's rendering but it will be executed line wise correct. And you were setting state of `deployed:1`  directly in the flow. So it will be executed right? You want some condition at which that code doesn't execute.